# Magento admin login issue after changing server

Tags: magento

I have changed domain of current magento(1.4.1.1) installation to a new one.
Everything except admin panel is working fine.
when i try to login to admin (i have correct username and password), i am not able to login and not getting any error also.
I have tried all the possible ways suggested in magento fourum and stack over flow but could not resolve it.
I tried commenting out the code in varien.php, deleting the cache etc
I am getting the same error in my local installation aswell.
Any help will be appreciated..
Regards,
Leo

Comment: What is your error ? Have you tried just to delete your cookies ?

Comment: I am not getting any error..it just redirects to the admin login page.. yes i have tried it by removing the cache as well

Comment: Just to be sure , did you try another browser/clean browser cache ?

Comment: try reindexing the URLs had the same problem fixed with that

Comment: clear the cache won't fix. Clear your COOKIES

Comment: Is your problem solved? What is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to set:

suhosin.session.encrypt = Off in php.ini when working with suhosin.

2) Use a different browser. I know it sounds stupid, but thats what was my issue.